# Design pattern for dependency graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, design-patterns

I have a program with a number of variables A, B, C..., and they have dependency relationship. For example, C's value depends on A and B's values. Whenever the value of a variable is changed, I need to update all its downstream variables. For example, if A's value is changed, I will need to recompute C's value. If C's value is changed, too, I will need to recompute the values of those variables dependent on C. Now I have code like this:

```
A a;
B b;
C c;

// ...

void updateC()
{
    C newC = calculateC(a, b);
    if (c != newC)
    {
        c = newC;
        updateD();
        updateE();
    }
}
```

As the number of variables grows this code is too difficult to maintain. There are also complex logic such as if updateD is successful then you do not need to call updateE. Is there a standard design pattern or library for such problems?

Comment: Look into directed graphs and trees

Comment: Learn the pattern Observer.

Comment: With Observer Pattern, you may register D and E to C. And register C to B and A.
D and E are observers for C, C is an observer for A and B.

Comment: This needs to be completely expressed as a data structure rather than function definitions for each node. But it depends on the connection rules. Can you have circular connections? Or are the connections simply branching out tree-like?

Comment: For sure this is about a graph (as said in the title). I just wonder if there is a common way to implement such graph. I have seen many implementations for other models such as state machines but nothing for this one. Maybe this model is not very commonly used.

Comment: The good thing about the observer pattern is that the predecessors instead of the successors are written in code. So it is less likely to miss a dependency graph edge. But it is still not 100% safe.

Comment: There should not be circular dependencies otherwise you cannot calculate the values in a cycle. It is also not always a tree because one variable can be dependent on more than one other variables.

Comment: Re: "if updateD is successful then you do not need to call updateE": Wait, why would that be? If E depends on C, then you should need to update it whenever C changes.

Comment: @ruakh In that case, D's value depends on C and E. If there is a feasible D for C and E, it indicates that E must also be feasible for C. It is just some problem-specific detail.

Comment: @Fan: I honestly don't understand what you're trying to say, but that doesn't sound like a "problem-specific detail" to me. If updates require custom logic like that, then that seems to undermine the entire rest of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you need to decouple the objects A, B, C... that can be achieved using a man-in-the-middle i.e., Mediator pattern:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern

Using the Eventbus pattern:

http://wiki.c2.com/?DataBusPattern

Using the Pub-Sub pattern:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish-subscribe_pattern

The Observer pattern:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

And more generally Reactive Programming:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming

Answer (score 0):

Compute the [transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure) of the graph in a matrix m. Now m(i,j) (or m(j,j)) will tell you if thing i is dependent on thing j. Multiplying this (or it's transpose) by a vector of what changed (with one's where thing j changes and zeroes elsewhere) will give you a vector of what you need to update.

Also, you would have to generate the [strict partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Strict_and_non-strict_partial_orders) and sort by that.

Comment: It gives you a vector of variables to update. But you do not know in which order they should be updated.

Comment: you would have to generate the strict partial order (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Strict_and_non-strict_partial_orders)  and sort by that.